# Moneris 3DS-Authentication request giving 303

Tags: 3d-secure, http-status-code-303

I have implemented Moneris 3DS2.2 on our platform in PHP , some how for live cards we are receiving 303 response code in response of 3DS-Authentication request.

Is billing details are required to be sent in 3DS-Authentication request.  Can we skip billing state (as state needs to be in  numeric IS0 3661-1 format) as test transactions including challenge and frictionless flow are successful without billing details as well, though we have passed billing details on production but still receiving 303 for some.

Can someone please help?

I have no idea what to try as response code is not giving any direction